# Kubernetes Dashboard Static Password FIle uer cannot list <resources>

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I had tried [Access-control#admin-privileges](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control#admin-privileges) to use dashboard and it works.
Then I tried Static Password File to login dashboard.

I added *--basic-auth-file=* to /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml, added --authentication-mode=basic to dashboard; then restarted kubelet.

The content of passowrd file  is something like this:

```
admin123,admin,admin
```

When I login dashboard as admin/admin identity, there is no common information but a lot of error messages shown:

```
persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "admin" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims in the namespace "default"
configmaps is forbidden: User "admin" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "default"
...
```

Seems the privilege of admin user was not enough, did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use rbac, try to give admin a proper clusterrole, like 'view', or you can give admin priviledge in abac.jsonl file.

Comment: kubectl create clusterrolebinding admin --clusterrole=admin --user=admin

Comment: The above command creates a user call admin with admin privilege(clusterrole).